# AES parameters specifications

Tags: algorithm-design

I'm writinig manager for all transformations which is described on https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

There are few questions about how cryptographic algorithm works.

I found on Wikipedia that AES can have 128, 192, 256 key sizes. But I cannot define sizes for IV.

I got this error:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: expected IV length of 16
```

So is it mean that for all AES transformations IV should have only one size (128-bit)?

Except ECB:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: ECB mode does not use an IV
```

I also noticed that AES/CBC/NoPadding doesn't work with any stream (it should be fixed). What the sense of this transformation if it cannot be applied to all data? But it works with any data if I preferred padding. Any explanations?

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: error:0607F08A:digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length
```

And the last question. For which modes IV is necessary/optional (it seems like necessary (not optional) for every mode except ECB) while encryption and for which is unnecessary while decryption?

Finally I should to create table for every mode (there is 6): CBC, CFB, CTR, CTS, ECB, OFB. Something like:
1. IV: necessary / optional / unnecessary.
2. IV for decryption: necessary / unnecessary.
3. Acceptable IV lengths.
4. Data should multiple of block length: true / false (block length).

Comment: I'm sorry, but your (minor?) edit didn't change the orientation of the question in any meaningful way. It still _looks_ like a "I need help debugging question".

Comment: @SEJPM I didn't talk about programming at Java or C++. Where is any code? I got first point: IV is necessary in all modes except ECB (when I initialized cipher without IV, Java just generated it in the hid way). Second point is really strange. I'll launch few tests to see what exactly is happened. Just need some time to preparation...

Comment: Also I found on Android Developers page info that the block size can be changed. So IV could be smaller. I also need to check it. All this are very bad described. Do you really think that programmers will know much about it?

Comment: @SEJPM CTS mode seems to work only when data => block size, right? Is this info is related to programming or cryptography? 

Comment: This question actually consists of *multiple questions* that are very basic. I have voted not to re-open for this reason. I strongly suggest you *read into cryptography before trying to use it for real world applications*. So although you could argue that it is not a programming related question, it still has issues severe enough not to reopen the question.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It is very basic for you only.  Anyway I got the info which I requested by launching tests, lol. If you are so smart, you could help by giving me the last answer. It is really possible to prefer smaller block for certain modes (CFB40, for example, that means that block size is 5 bytes), but it throws me exception that IV should be 16 bytes. Explanations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is it mean that for all AES transformations IV should have only one
>   size (128-bit)?

**No, not really.** The acceptable size for the IV is defined by the [*mode of operation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). Some modes require a full [*block size*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_size_(cryptography)) as the IV (CBC, CTR, ...), others a bit less and again others take just about any length of an IV that you throw at them (GCM, ...).

> What the sense of this transformation if it cannot be applied to all
>   data?

[CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#CBC) works by chaining *full blocks* together. Thus you need to process a multiple of the block size. Normally if we don't have a multiple of the block size we [*pad*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) our data to this size, but in this case you chose to disable padding and as such the length restriction applies.

> For which modes IV is necessary/optional?

Any mode that does not take an IV is trivially insecure under standard security definitions. As such it is **strongly recommended against** using any such mode (like ECB or SIV) unless *absolutely* neccessary. Every other mode requires an IV. And if you need an IV for encryption you'll also need one for decryption and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's still unclear. I updated my question (see at the end). I need more concrete info. I tried to decrypt data in CFB mode without IV: it was successfully decrypted. Also I tried to encrypt data in CTR then decrypt it in CFB without IV: works. It seems like IV really not necessary for decryption. Can you explain it?

Comment: @Daimonium I suspect that either the engine you used used a) an implicit (constant?) IV that you didn't even notice or b) CFB should be self-synchronizing as a mode meaning that it can quickly recover from a block lost (including the IV) and thus you _could_ trade losing some plaintext against using an IV.

Comment: I got the issue. I wrote this scheme: generate IV - cipher.init(Key, IV) - pin IV at start to encrypted data. When I decrypted data: cipher.init(Key) (without IV). But IV already was as the first block. That's what confused me. Now it's clear.